# Default div-grid margin

Tags: html, margin

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5aYj.png)

I set all margins equal to 0. I expected there would be no spaces between my div-cells. But as you can see from the picture, my expectations were failed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5aYj.png

I experimented and found out that the spaces disappear when margin is set to -3px. Can anyone explain to me this behavior?

Comment: It's better to post code as working text snippet, not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, the line breaks between the divs cause this (put all code in one line for proof).

One solution is to set font-size:0 on the outer div and set it back to normal on the inner ones.

Comment: yeah! it worked! thank you!